# Neo4j batch delete

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

I use following util class for Neo4j database cleaning:

```
public class Neo4jUtils {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jUtils.class);

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

    public static void cleanDb(Neo4jTemplate template) {
        logger.info("Cleaning database");
        long deletedNodesCount = 0;
        do {
            GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService = template.getGraphDatabaseService();
            Transaction tx = graphDatabaseService.beginTx();
            try {
                Result<Map<String, Object>> result = template.query("MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT " + BATCH_SIZE + " OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r RETURN count(n) as count", null);
                deletedNodesCount = (long) result.single().get("count");
                tx.success();
                logger.info("Deleted " + deletedNodesCount + " nodes...");
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                logger.error("Error while deleting database", th);
                throw th;
            } finally {
                tx.close();
            }
        } while (deletedNodesCount > 0);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have limited batch size to 1000 but anyway, during the delete operation first batch deletes ~300000 entities and the rest of the batches delete ~2000 entities in each batch.

Can you please tell me why I have these big numbers in case of using `BATCH_SIZE = 1000;` How to fix this function in order to truly limit batch size to 1000 nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably double counting the nodes because you have multiple relations to them. Your query should indeed delete 1000 nodes but you return the number of combinations (n,r).

You could:

Change your query to print the unique nodes:

```
MATCH (n) WITH n LIMIT 1000 OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r RETURN count(DISTINCT n) as count
```

Or print the number of nodes remaining after each delete and check if it is 1000 less than previously

```
MATCH (n) RETURN count(n) as count
```